# What can lead to failures in appending data to a file?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, windows-7, file-io

I maintain a program that is responsible for collecting data from a data acquisition system and appending that data to a very large (size > 4GB) binary file.  Before appending data, the program must validate the header of this file in order to ensure that the meta-data in the file matches that which has been collected.  In order to do this, I open the file as follows:

data_file = fopen(file_name, "rb+");

I then seek to the beginning of the file in order to validate the header.  When this is done, I seek to the end of the file as follows:

_fseeki64(data_file, _filelengthi64(data_file), SEEK_SET);

At this point, I write the data that has been collected using fwrite().  I am careful to check the return values from all I/O functions.

One of the computers (windows 7 64 bit) on which we have been testing this program intermittently shows a condition where the data appears to have been written to the file yet neither the file's last changed time nor its size changes.  If any of the calls to fopen(), fseek(), or fwrite() fail, my program will throw an exception which will result in aborting the data collection process and logging the error.  On this machine, none of these failures seem to be occurring.  Something that makes the matter even more mysterious is that, if a restore point is set on the host file system, the problem goes away only to re-appear intermittently appear at some future time.

We have tried to reproduce this problem on other machines (a vista 32 bit operating system) but have had no success in replicating the issue (this doesn't necessarily mean anything since the problem is so intermittent in the first place.

Has anyone else encountered anything similar to this?  Is there a potential remedy?

**Further Information**

I have now found that the failure occurs when fflush() is called on the file and that the win32 error that is being returned by GetLastError() is 665 (ERROR_FILE_SYSTEM_LIMITATION).  Searching google for this error leads to a bunch of reports related to "extents" for SQL server files.  I suspect that there is some sort of journaling resource that the file system is reporting and this because we are growing a large file by opening it, appending a chunk of data, and closing it.  I am now looking for understanding regarding this particular error with the hope for coming up with a valid remedy.

Comment: You say "the data appears to have been written to the file".  Is the file modified as expected, then - albeit with the size / modify date not reflecting this?

Comment: No, what I mean by this is merely that the return values from fwrite() indicate that the data was successfully written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file append is failing because of a file system fragmentation limit.  The question was answered in [What factors can lead to Win32 error 665 (file system limitation)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7323760/what-factors-can-lead-to-win32-error-665-file-system-limitation)