# What factors can lead to Win32 error 665 (file system limitation)?

Tags: c++, winapi, ntfs

I maintain an application that collects data from a datalogger and appends that data to the end of a binary file.  The nature of this system is that the file can grow large (> 4 gigabytes) small steps at a time.  On of the users of my application has seen cases on his NTFS partition where the attempts to append data fail.  The error is being reported as a result of a call to fflush().  When this happens, the return value for GetLastError() is 665 (ERROR_FILE_SYSTEM_LIMITATION). MSDN gives the following [description](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for this error

> The requested operation could not be completed due to a file system limitation

A search for this error code on google gives results related to SQL server with VERY large files (tens of gigabytes) but, at present, our file is much smaller.  This user has not been able to get the file to grow beyond 10 gigabytes.  We can temporarily correct the situation when we do some operation (like copying the file) that forces some sort of rewrite in the file system.  Unfortunately, I am not sure what is going on to put us in this condition in the first place.  What specific conditions in an NTFS file system can lead to this particular error being reported on a call to fflush()?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mikelag/archive/2011/02/09/how-fragmentation-on-incorrectly-formatted-ntfs-volumes-affects-exchange.aspx) helps. It is about Exchange, but maybe you can find something there.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;967351

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This sounds like you've reached a limit in the fragmentation of the file. In other words, each flush is creating a new extent (fragment) of the file and the filesystem is having a hard time finding a place to keep track of the list of fragments. That would explain why copying the file helps -- it creates a new file with fewer fragments.

Another thing that would probably work is defragmenting the file (using Sysinternals's [`contig`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897428) utility you may be able to do so while it's in use). You can also use `contig` to tell you how many fragments the file has. I'm guessing it's on the order of one million.

If you have to flush the file frequently and can't defrag it, something you can do is simply create the file fairly large in the first place (to allocate the space all at once) and then write to successive bytes of the file rather than append.

If you're brave (and your process has admin access), you can defragment the file yourself with a few API calls: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363911(v=VS.85).aspx

Comment: I was not aware of the contig utility and it appears to be a useful tool.  Unfortunately, it was not able to defragment the file.  The error code was the same (665).  Apparently contig is unable to defragment a file that is too fragmented.

Comment: @Jon: Yes, I'm afraid you would have to run `contig` *before* it got that big. What does `contig -a` say about your file?

Comment: contig -a reported that the file had 77771 fragments.  I copied the file and contig then reported that the file had one fragment.  The reported number of fragments seems like an odd sort of limit in the file system. Is there some sort of hard limit or is there some sort of indirection going on here?

Comment: @Jon: Windows can benefit a lot if you set the expected file size up front (`SetEndOfFile`). This is a less hacky version of creating a large file and overwriting it.

Comment: @MSalters: How is using `SetEndOfFile` different from creating a large file and overwriting it?

Comment: @Gabe: Semantically identical, but you don't need 4Gb's of zeroes in RAM to write 4GB of zeroes to disk.